# What is difference btw Pandas/Numpy datetime64 and datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the difference between Pandas/Numpy **datetime64** and **datetime64[ns]**? Also, how do you select a Pandas DataFrame column with dtype **datetime64[ns]**?

I tried the following:

```
for col in df.columns:  
   if (df[col].dtype == np.datetime64[ns]): #If column has dtype datetime64[ns]  
       print(col)
       function(df[col]) ##apply a function to this column   
## RESULT: NameError: name 'ns' is not defined  
## If I try == np.datetime64, nothing gets printed.
```

I also tried:

```
for col in df.columns: 
   if (df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]'): 
       print(col)
       function(df[col])  
## RESULT: This works but it also print Columns with dtype object.
```

What can I do to select only columns that have dtype **datetime64[ns]?**

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it has answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Use select_dtypes.
Consider this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': pd.date_range(end = dt.datetime.today(), periods = 2), \
'date2': pd.date_range(end = dt.datetime.today(), periods = 2),\
'val1': np.arange(2),'bool': [True, False]})
```

df.dtypes

```
bool               bool
date1    datetime64[ns]
date2    datetime64[ns]
val1              int64
```

You can use select_dtypes to select datetime,

```
df_new = df.select_dtypes(include = ['datetime'])
```

You get

```
    date1                       date2
0   2017-12-05 11:02:05.580203  2017-12-05 11:02:05.580889
1   2017-12-06 11:02:05.580203  2017-12-06 11:02:05.580889
```